# How to access RTMPTE Stream in C#

Tags: c#, .net, actionscript-3, streaming, rtmp

Is there a possible method that i can read a [RTMPTE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashlite/dev/4/WSa2ec538c80d458334e75085e123e08b609b-8000.html)  stream and play it in c#

Answer (score 0):

It is been made possible by FlowPlayer from Adobe Flash now. It provides best secure rtmpe streaming. The details of implementation can be found in their official page [here](http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html) and [this one](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/streaming/secure-wowza.html).